# validate using session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

if session is null means i have to redirect to login page, for that i am checking session value in each and every page in project any other method to that, using c#.net

thank u

Answer (score 1):

Check the example in OP's post in this thread: [add a custom base class for web forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053082/add-a-custom-base-class-for-web-forms)

A custom base Page class is the correct place to create such functionality.