# add a custom base class for web forms

Tags: asp.net

I want to add a custom base class for all of my web forms. I created a "App_code" folder in my asp.net web project and add a simple base page class like this:

```
namespace MySite.Web
{
    // base page for all the pages that need localization
    public class LocalizationPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I try to let asp.net web form to inherit from this base page. I have something like this:

```
using MySite.Web;

namespace MySite.Public
{
    public partial class RegisterPage : LocalizationPage 
    {
    }
}
```

Now I run into problem where Visual Studio doesn't recognize the LocalizationPage class I created. On the above code snippet, LocalizationPage is not highlighted as a class. And when I try to compile, I got the following error message:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name
>   'LocalizationPage' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly
>   reference?)

Please advice...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open the properties for the file in the App_Code folder, and check the `Build Action`. Change it to `Compile` so that the file is included in the compilation, and the class will exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now!

It took 1 min to have my question solved! yay StackOverflow!!!

Comment: I'm fairly new to WebForms (I'm an MVC guy) and this really helped me figure out how to create a base class. Thank you!